# C error handling best practice - use of exit()?

Tags: c, error-handling

I have a c program which defines the following function:

```
void logFatal(char *msg, enum errors error)
{
    fprintf(stderr, msg);
    exit(error);
}
```

In the rest of the program if anything happens that means the program will not function properly if execution continues (typical example being a call to `malloc` fails to allocate memory), then I call `logFatal` and the program exits, where-ever it happens to be.

Is this good/bad practice?

Comment: It's not so much a question of good/bad practice, more so a matter of taste

Comment: For fatal errors, where you can't continue, there's really nothing else you can realistically do.

Comment: Malloc returning NULL is far from fatal...

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are not writing a library for other people ;) you are free to do this. It is usually used as a last resource though, because with most errors it is enough to just cancel the action.

Imagine this error:

- user clicks *open file*
- file doesn't exist
- program exits

That feels a bit harsh... So in that case it is better to handle the error with a message to the user etc. But since you didn't specify what kind of application, i can't tell you anything about that, but malloc failures usually indicate big trouble, so in that case it's probably best to *just exit*.

Comment: Thanks. It is a console application which takes a config file as input, so not much room for asking users to redo stuff while it waits :) But yes, I am talking about fatal errors really (or errors where you know that if you continue execution you will produce garbage results etc..)

Comment: Well, then it is the only soluting, since you are already reporting back what went wrong :)